# Why am I not getting padding on the right side of my string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that constructs pyramids. The pyramid comes in an array with each floor being made of asterisks, however, when I try to center each floor with padding, I'm only receiving padding on the left side of each string. Why is this happening?

```
public class Kata
{
  public static string[] TowerBuilder(int nFloors)
  {
    string[] tower = new string[nFloors];
    
    for( int floorNum = 0; floorNum < nFloors; floorNum++ ) {
      int numOfStars = 2 * (floorNum + 1) - 1;
      int maxStars = 2 * nFloors - 1;
      
      char star = '*';  
      string floor = new string( star, numOfStars );
  
      int totalPadding = maxStars - floorNum - 1;
      int padding = totalPadding / 2;
      string centeredFloor = floor.PadLeft(padding).PadRight(padding);

      tower[floorNum] = centeredFloor;
    } 
  
    return tower;
  }
}
```

Comment: The integer passed into [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_) is the total final length of the string. Since your result from `PadLeft(padding)` already gives a string with `str.Length == padding`, then `PadRight(padding)` will not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The argument in `PadLeft` and `PadRight` specifies the total length of the final string, not the number of characters to append. You'd need to use eg

```
string centeredFloor = floor.PadLeft(numOfStars+padding)
                            .PadRight(numOfStars+totalPadding);
```